# prometheus discovery of dynamic targets with custom script

Tags: prometheus, service-discovery

I use prometheus to monitor the service which expose the metrics on dynamic port, port changes on every restart.
I created the script which checks service endpoint port, how may i send new target endpoint  port to prometheus? Could you give me an example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus supports various mechanisms for service discovery; everything [`{something}_sd_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config)

Probably (!) the simplest for use with a script is [File-based service discovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config). This requires updates to be made to a file containing JSON or YAML that describes the target(s) (`host:port`)

Prometheus' documentation includes an [example](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/file-sd/#use-file-based-service-discovery-to-discover-scrape-targets) that describes how to use file-based service discovery using a static JSON file.

In your case, your script would update the JSON file whenever the service's port changes.

Comment: thanks it helped, my issue is that i didn't know that changes in file_sd_configs: json/yml files are automatically propagated to prometheus, i thought it will be needed to restart prometheus every time. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm pleased to hear that it helped. Yes, documentation can always be improved but the example I referenced is good. The file is parsed upon each configurable `refresh_interval` and the target list is then refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Another good option additionally to [file_sd_configs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#file_sd_configs) is to use [http_sd_configs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#http_sd_configs). It allows implementing arbitrary service discovery for Prometheus inside a simple http service. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/http_sd/) for details.